# Is it possible to run rascal programs from the command line?

Tags: command-line, rascal

I know how to run rascal code from within eclipse and how to use the REPL, but I don't know how I can run a rascal file (or group of rascal files) as a program from the command line.

When I try the following, I get a parse error:

```
$ java -Xmx1G -Xss32m -jar rascal-shell-stable.jar mymodule.rsc
Version: 0.7.2.201501130937
Parse error in cwd:///mymodule.rsc from <1,11> to <1,12>
```

The contents of `mymodule.rsc`:

```
module mymodule

println("hello world");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your `mymodule.rsc` is actually syntactically incorrect and will also give parse errors in the Eclipse IDE. Here is an improved version:

```
module mymodule

import IO;

value main(list[value] args) {
    println("hello world");
}
```

Bonus: you should also add `import IO;` to make the `println` function available.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot you can't have normal statements outside a function. I added a `void main(list[str] args)` function to enclose my "hello world" and it works! It is confusing however, that the console inside eclipse does not require me to `import IO;` before a `println`, while code inside modules does not work without it. Also, when I run using "Run As Rascal Application", I get the following error: `The called signature: main(),
does not match the declared signature: void main(list[value]);`. Why is the expected signature different from when I call the module from the command line?

Comment: (1) Inside Eclipse IO is imported automatically as a convenience for the user. The incompatibility with the command line is indeed annoying. (2) The call should be `main([])` (argument is an empty list).

Comment: Regarding the main method in a console app, you can also use keyword parameters `main(str bar ="foobar")` which is available in the commandline as `-bar barfoo`

Comment: Is it possible to suppress the "Version: X" line emitted by the interpreter?