# How can I compile Rascal into a stand-alone command-line executable?

Tags: rascal

I am in need of creating compiled, stand-alone, command-line, terminal-I/O, old-style-Unix executables from Rascal source code. I do realize that the proper question might have to include "modulo invoking a JVM explicitly", although it would be great to get rid of that as well. Just to be clear that I'm talking about, here's the first program I'd like to compile.

```
module hello
import IO;
void main()
{
    println( "Hello, sailor." );
}
```

Implicit in the question is "What's the proper signature of `main()`?", but that's subsidiary to the question of how to get a compiled executable.

I would expect that the compiler can be run from the command line itself, and not only from within Eclipse. I need to automate compilation within a build tool.

How do I do this?

There are two related SO questions already, neither of which provides an answer.

- [Is it possible to run rascal programs from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046840/is-it-possible-to-run-rascal-programs-from-the-command-line). This question asks about using the Rascal interpreter, not the compiler. There's also spurious output of the Rascal version number in this example.
- [Export a Rascal project to a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435487/export-a-rascal-project-to-a-jar-file). This question isn't completely clear, but the answer there most relevant to the question here involves linking in the Rascal shell. I don't need the shell and I'd like to leave its code out of the executable.